# Select2 Get selected option data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

`$("#e2").select2("val")` returns me the value, but I wan't to get the `.$listtypes['name'] .` ether from data-name or from the option tag display.

I want to get the option data-name for the selected option, how can I accomplish this?

This is my option generator

```
foreach($core->list_types() as $listtypes){
echo "
<option 
  data-name='".$listtypes['name'] ."' 
  value='".$listtypes['id']."'>
  ".$listtypes['name'] ."
</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you can use this

```
$("#e2 option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 32):

**Try this:**

`$('#e2').select2('data')`

return selected option data

Comment: Might be worth noting that this returns a javascript array. Documentation link:https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections#using-the-data-method

Answer (score 9):

This work for me:

On simple **select2** to get label value:

`$('#myVar').select2('data')[0].<name_label_from_data_input>`

May be helpful do an data dump from **select2** variable:

```
$('#myVar').on('change', function (evt) {
  if ($('#myVar').select2('val') != null){
    console.log($('#myVar').select2('data')[0]);    
  }
});
```

And catch your the label's name attribute.

Good luck!

Comment: I wouldn't call it the "label value" because that implies (to me) `$('#myVar').val()`, but your answer is very useful because from `$('#myVar').select2('data')[0]` one can get properties `id`, `text`, `title`, and the underlying `option` element via the property `element`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this script

```
$('#editable-select').on('select2:select', function (e) {
            var data = e.params.data;
            console.log(data);
    alert(data['text']);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks that @Kishan and @xploshioOn's answers won't work on v4.0+.

Try this: `$("#e2").text().trim()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the attr method `.attr("data-name")` on your selector.