# How to add a data-* attribute to each option when creating a select2 input?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using **select2** to select from a list the image that I want to be displayed on the screen.
For this I need to set an attribute on each option: s3_key

I want to put this attribute when the select2 is created

I have seen solutions to add data-* attributes when an option is selected. This solution doesn't work for me because
if the input already has a value selected when loading the web page, the image has to be displayed automatically.

```
      $('#id-gci-main').select2({
        language: '<?= getLanguage() ?>',
        closeOnSelect: true,
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: '',
        data: <?= $aJsonGCIsPrincipalesOtorgados ?>
    }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
        var data = e.params.data;                
        $(this).children('[value="'+data['id']+'"]').attr({
            'data-s3_key':data["s3_key"], //dynamic value from data array
        });
    }).val(0).trigger('load');
```

The variable $aJsonGCIsPrincipalesOtorgados has the following structure:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'xxxx'.
        s3_key: '/xx/image.png'
    },
```

Is there any way to do this?

**Example code:**

https://jsfiddle.net/JorgePalaciosZaratiegui/fhad7gmr/12/

Comment: don't do that, simply use a js Object

Comment: What do you mean exactly @MisterJojo? Can you give me an example of your idea?

Comment: Is it possible to make it more **reproducible**, like adding the html for that as well?

Comment: I have put an example link @Cypherjac ;)

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? If you want to customize the way that select options are displayed, you can use `templateResult ` option: https://select2.org/dropdown#templating and also `templateSelection` https://select2.org/selections#templating`

Comment: The select is part of a form. Contains a list of names that correspond to images.
Its value is saved in DB.
When the list has an item selected, the selected image is automatically displayed. For this I need the data-s3_key attribute that contains the url @andreivictor

Comment: The [tag:select2] SO wiki page shows you how to do this.  Here's it applied to your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w2npyLr3/  **edit** your own snippet already shows this: `var data = e.params.data;`

Comment: I might be missing the problem or it's an XY problem.  You have the s3_key `data["s3_key"]` - why do you need/want to add it as an attribute?  You just state *For this I need to set an attribute on each option*

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440686/2181514) you can retrieve the selected data at any time:  `$("#id-gci-main").select2("data")[0].s3_key` https://jsfiddle.net/w2npyLr3/1/ so there's really no need to store it as an attribute, and as noted above, use templateResult if you want image shown on each "option".   But that depends on what's *reading* the attribute - and whether it's reading it from the select2's list or the underlying `select` - hence an XY problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m oh i didn't know this! Thank you very much, I think this can help me for what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

don't do that, simply use a js Object `select2data`:

```js
const data1 = 
  [ { id: 'key_1', text: 'YY',  s3_key: 'xxxx/yy.png'  } 
  , { id: 'key_2', text: 'BB',  s3_key: 'wwww/bb.png'  } 
  , { id: 'key_3', text: 'AAA', s3_key: 'wwww/aaa.png' } 
  ] 
const select2data = data1.reduce((r,{id,...more})=>(r[id]=more,r),{}) 

// console.log( select2data )


$("#id-gci-main").select2(
    { closeOnSelect : true
    , allowClear    : true
    , placeholder   : ''
    , data          : data1
    }
).on('change', function(e) 
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log( select2data[this.value].s3_key )
  });
```

```css
#id-gci-main {
  width : 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select id="id-gci-main" ></select>
```

Comment: I have tried to change my data variable but the select tag does not show any value. Now, I have put an example link in the question

Comment: @JorgePalaciosZaratiegui I changed my answer